# What is the alternative of Selenium for executing Js in Python-Scrapy?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, scrapy

I want to execute JavaScript's function in Python-Scrapy, before, i used Selenium, but Selenium is too much slow for scraping the big sites.

I would like to know what's the best alternative for selenium for executing js in Scrapy?

Comment: Have you tried webdriver.js ?

Comment: @Karthikeyan yes, it's not a good choice for the big site

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Splash - A javascript rendering service](https://github.com/scrapinghub/splash)

> Splash is a javascript rendering service with an HTTP API. It's a lightweight browser with an HTTP API, implemented in Python using Twisted and QT.
>
> It's fast, lightweight and state-less which makes it easy to distribute.

Bonus points for it being developed by the same guys who are developing Scrapy.